# For a small Database site, should i choose SQL CE or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce-4

I have a website with not more than 100 products which shall grow to 1000-5000 over the period of time if the website grows.

I like SQL CE as its hassle free in deployment and backup. The only thing i am afraid is the performance i will receive from it. My website has 5 tables in the db and i am using entity framework, so a lot of querying goes in and out.

Should i go with the SQL server at the very start or a SQL CE is decent enough in performance for a small to medium ranged website.

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly go for SQL Server. If you have a small budget I would recommend the Express version if you don't do anything fancy : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

We use SQL Express for our development environment with more than 20 tables and almost 100000k rows and we never had any performance issue !

If SQL Express is not available, I would still pick SQL Server since no new version of SQL CE is planned and it does not support stored procedures, XML data types, ODBC. Also, SQL CE is optimized for an architecture where all applications share the same memory pool, wich is not the case here with a small website database.

Comment: The express edition is rarely available at web hosters. That's why I compared SQL CE and SQL SERVER

Comment: I would still go with SQL Server since no new version of SQL CE is planned in the future. Also, i doesn't even support ODBC (no driver) and stored procedures...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact